# Prove the inequality with mathematical induction

Tags: inequality, induction

> Prove that the inequality:$$\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}\geq\left(\frac{n\sqrt{n}+1}{2}\right)$$ by mathematical induction, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

What I tried :

Step 1:

$p(1)$ : $\sqrt{1}\geq\left(\frac{1\times\sqrt{1}+1}{2}\right) \implies 1=1$ .

Step 2:
$k\in\mathbb{N}$.

$p(k)$: $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{k}\geq\left(\frac{k\sqrt{k}+1}{2}\right)$ which is assumed.

$p(k+1)$: $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}\geq\left(\frac{(k+1)\sqrt{k+1}+1}{2}\right)$

$\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{k}\geq\left(\frac{k\sqrt{k}+1}{2}\right)$ this part is $p(k)$, so I am going to add $\sqrt{k+1}$ on both sides:

$$\left(\frac{k\sqrt{k}+1}{2}\right)+ \sqrt{k+1}$$

From here I don’t know how to continue and I’m not sure if the adding part is even helpful.

I hope the question is understandable.
Thanks !

Comment: Looks good so far. To complete the induction step, you want to show that your last expression is $ \geq [(k+1)\sqrt{k+1} + 1] / 2$. Why is this true?

Comment: @CalvinLin you are asking why do i think p(k) is true or about the next step where you have to prove what you wrote  ?

Comment: What they are hinting at is that you need to add $\frac{k\sqrt{k}+1}{2}+\sqrt{k+1}$ and prove that it is greater or equal to $\frac{(k+1)\sqrt{k+1}+1}{2}$

Comment: @AP ok,thanks !

Comment: So now, you just have to check that $$k\sqrt k\ge(k-1)\sqrt{k+1}.$$ Hint: square both sides.

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks !